# Stored proc to perform same operations for different tables

Tags: sql-server

```
                       Month        Registered Users        Daily - Total Accounted Time (Hrs)


                         Oct             73                      5.90
                         Nov             70                      6.40    
                         Dec             81                      5.80
```

> I have 3 tables in these same format and I've to perform same
>   operations for all these 3 tables. Is there any possible way to
>   perform them using a single query, in a stored proc?

Comment: `UNION ALL` ? Anyway your question a bit unclear for me...

Comment: For eg: I've to perform Select * from table1, similar queries I need to perform for the rest. These 3 tables have same columnheaders and same number of columns.I want these 3 answers in 3 different scenarios so Union won't help.

Comment: "Is there any possible way to perform them using a single query" - 
What operation you want to perform?

Comment: if it's  in a  stored proc, then why does it need to be a single query?  why not have 3 queries in one stored proc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this, You should make use of dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc1 @tablename VARCHAR(256),@groupbycolumn VARCHAR(256)='',@filter VARCHAR(256)=''
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(max)=''

      SET @cmd='select * from ' + @tablename +''
      --using where
      --SET @cmd='select * from ' + @tablename +' where id='+@filter
      --using group by columns
      --SET @cmd='select '+@groupbycolumn+',max(column) from ' + @tablename + ' '+@groupbycolumn 

      EXEC Sp_executesql
        @cmd
  END 

exec dbo.Proc1 @tablename='table1'--returns results of table1
exec dbo.Proc1 @tablename='table2'--returns results of table2
exec dbo.Proc1 @tablename='table3'--returns results of table3
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but how to give group by or where clause in the select statement?

Comment: SET @cmd='select '+@groupbycolumn+',max(column) from ' + @tablename + ' '+@groupbycolumn . This line is giving this error message:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'. Is max(column)  possible in the select query?